# Print coloured emojis using imagick in php

Tags: php, imagick

I want to print the captions imported from facebook/instagram in an image and save it. I want to do this using imagick library with php as I am creating the base image using imagick. The normal text prints properly but the emojis that are imported do not get printed as coloured emoji's. Can anyone suggest how coloured emojis can be printed using imagick.

What I have tried:

```
$eachpageimg = new Imagick ();
$eachpageimg->setResolution ( 300 , 300 );
$eachpageimg->newImage (1050, 1260 , 'rgb(255,255,255)');
$eachpageimg->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$eachpageimg->setImageFormat ('jpeg');
$eachpageimg->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

$text3 = '"my cutie pie\\uD83C\\uDF82\\uD83C\\uDF70honey cookie\\uD83C\\uDF69"';

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' );
$pixel->setColorValue(Imagick::COLOR_ALPHA, .8);

$draw->setStrokeColor('rgb(0,0,0)');
$draw->setFillColor ('rgb(0,0,0)');
$draw->setFont ("ROBOTO-REGULAR");
$draw->setFontSize(70);
$xpos = 10;
$ypos = 200;
$eachpageimg->annotateImage($draw, $xpos, $ypos, 0, json_decode($text3));

$filename = 'saved.jpg';
// SAVE FINAL page image
file_put_contents ($filename, $eachpageimg);
```